# How to replace a part of variable name in a template file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a file from a sample template file.
I need to replace ONLY `$UPPERINTERFACE` with `interface`.

This is the sample `template.txt`

```
localparam $UPPERINTERFACE_WDTH = 1;
localparam $UPPERINTERFACE_DPTH = 8;
localparam $UPPERINTERFACE_WTCHD = 2;
```

This is the code:

```
from string import Template
intf = "interface"
rdfh = open("template.txt", "r").readlines()
wrfh = open("myfile.txt", "w")
for line in rdfh:
    s = Template(line)
    s = s.substitute(UPPERINTERFACE=intf.upper())
    wrfh.write(s)
rdfh.close()
wrfh.close()
```

Expected output:

```
localparam interface_WDTH = 1;
localparam interface_DPTH = 8;
localparam interface_WTCHD = 2;
```

As it is taking `$UPPERINTERFACE_WDTH` as a variable to be replaced, I am getting following error:

```
KeyError: 'UPPERINTERFACE_WDTH'
```

Is there any way I can replace only `$UPPERINTERFACE` with `interface` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curly braces `{}` to narrow down the template key as in following template string:

```
>>> line = 'localparam ${UPPERINTERFACE}_WDTH = 1;'
>>> Template(line).substitute(UPPERINTERFACE=intf.upper())
'localparam INTERFACE_WDTH = 1;'
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) states the following:

> `${identifier}` is equivalent to `$identifier`. It is required when valid identifier characters follow the placeholder but are not part of the placeholder, such as `"${noun}ification"`.

Comment: I think you have missed last line of my question. I need to replace ONLY `$UPPERINTERFACE` with `interface`.